# Some issues with proving that a sequence is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

I recently **tried** (in the sense that I believe the thesis holds) to prove that, given $a\in\mathbb{R}^+$, there exists

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\sqrt[n]{\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/5\rfloor}{n-4k\choose k}a^{-5k}}\in\mathbb{R}$$

For those who do not like the floor brackets, $\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/5\rfloor}{n-4k\choose k}a^{-5k}=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}{n-4k\choose k}a^{-5k}$.

Or one can *also* observe that it is sufficient to prove it for the subsequence $(n_s:=5s)_{s\in\mathbb{N}}$, which amounts to prove the existence of

$$\lim_{s\rightarrow+\infty}\sqrt[s]{\sum_{k=0}^s{5s-4k\choose k}a^{-5k}}\in\mathbb{R}$$

While showing that

$$\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}^+}\sqrt[n]{\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/5\rfloor}{n-4k\choose k}a^{-5k}}\le 2\max(a,1)\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}^+}\sqrt[n]{n}\le 4\max(a,1)$$

is pretty straight forward, I'm having several issues with showing that the series is convergent.

I tried computations with a couple of values of $a$ and not only there was convergence, but it seemed to be definitely monotone increasing.

My attempts to prove any of that were not particularly fruitful, though.

A useful thing to know is that it comes from a power series: indeed, $\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}{n-4k\choose k}a^{-5k}$ is the $n$-th coefficient of the Taylor series at $0$ of $$\frac{1}{1-x-\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^5}$$

So, if the thesis holds, the limit must be the inverse of the positive real root of $x^5+a^4x-a^5$.

If someone more skillful could solve it, I'd be overjoyed. Thank you in advance.

**Added** I also tried to prove that $\lim_n \left(\left(\frac{1}{c_n}\right)^5+\frac{a^4}{c_n}-a^5\right)=0$, but I could not go through. Maybe it's just me, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A useful thing to know is that it comes from a power series: indeed, $\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}{n-4k\choose k}a^{-5k}$ is the $n$-th coefficient of the Taylor series at $0$ of $$\frac{1}{1-x-\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^5}$$

This is the key. Let $\zeta$ be the positive zero of $p(z) = 1 - z - \left(\frac{z}{a}\right)^5$. Then $\zeta$ is the zero of $p$ with the strictly smallest modulus, and it is a simple zero ($p'(t) \leqslant -1$ for $t\in [0,+\infty)$). Thus

$$g(z) = \frac{1}{1-z-\left(\frac{z}{a}\right)^5} - \frac{1}{p'(\zeta)(z-\zeta)}$$

is holomorphic in a disk with radius $r > \zeta$. Let the Taylor series of $g$ be

$$g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \gamma_n z^n.$$

Further we have

$$\frac{1}{z-\zeta} = -\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{\zeta^{n+1}}.$$

Then we find

$$a_n := \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n-4k}{k}a^{-5k} = \gamma_n - \frac{1}{p'(\zeta)\zeta^{n+1}}.$$

Taking $n$-th roots, we obtain

$$\sqrt[n]{a_n} = \frac{1}{\zeta}\sqrt[n]{\gamma_n\zeta^n - \frac{1}{p'(\zeta)\zeta}} = \zeta^{-1}\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{\zeta\lvert p'(\zeta)\rvert}}\sqrt[n]{1- p'(\zeta)\gamma_n\zeta^{n+1}}.$$

But

$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{\zeta\lvert p'(\zeta)\rvert}} \to 1,$$

and since the radius of convergence of $g$ is greater than $\zeta$, we have

$$\gamma_n \zeta^n \to 0,$$

whence

$$1- p'(\zeta)\gamma_n\zeta^{n+1} \to 1$$

and also

$$\sqrt[n]{1- p'(\zeta)\gamma_n\zeta^{n+1}} \to 1.$$

Thus $\sqrt[n]{a_n} \to \zeta^{-1}$.

Comment: Just one thing that I thought afterwards: how do you prove that the radius of convergence of $\sum_n\gamma_nz^n$ is bigger than $\zeta$? Is there some general result guaranteeing this?

Comment: The radius of convergence is the distance from the centre of development to the nearest singularity. The singularities of $g$ are the zeros of $1-z-(z/a)^5$, except for $\zeta$, since we subtracted the principal part of $\frac{1}{1-z-(z/a)^5}$ in $\zeta$. The other zeros all have strictly larger modulus than $\zeta$, so the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $g$ is larger than $\zeta$.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your time: I was unfamiliar with the result that the radius of convergence was exactly the distance from the center to the nearest singulariy (i.e. that a complex power series couldn't cease to converge *just because*). @DanielFischer

Comment: Daniel, I had a couple of, quite possibly, naïve questions.  First, while $p(z)$ has only one real root $\zeta$, and $\zeta>0$, how can one assert that $\zeta$ is the root with the smallest modulus?  Second, if $\zeta$ is the root with the smallest modulus, then wouldn't $g(z)$ be analytic in a disc with radius $r<\zeta$ and not $r>\zeta$ as written herein?  +1 for the nice answer!  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV We have $1 = \zeta + (\zeta/a)^5 = \lvert \zeta\rvert + \lvert \zeta/a\rvert^5$ since $\zeta$ and $a$ are positive. If $w$ is any zero of $p$, then $1 = w + (w/a)^5 = \lvert w+(w/a)^5\rvert \leqslant \lvert w\rvert + \lvert w/a\rvert^5$. We have equality if and only if $(w/a)^5$ is a positive multiple of $w$, i.e. $w^4/a^5 \geqslant 0$, or simply $w^4 \geqslant 0$. But then $w+(w/a)^5 = w(1+w^4/a^5)$ is positive if and only if $w > 0$, so for $w\neq \zeta$ we have $\lvert \zeta\rvert + \lvert \zeta/a\rvert^5 = 1 < \lvert w\rvert + \lvert w/a\rvert^5$, and that implies

Comment: $\lvert\zeta\rvert < \lvert w\rvert$. We have subtracted the principal part of $\frac{1}{p(z)}$ to obtain $g$, hence the poles of the rational function $g$ are the zeros of $p$ that are different from $\zeta$. Let $\eta$ be a zero of $p$ such that its modulus is second smallest (since $p$ has only one real zero and real coefficients, the choice of $\eta$ is not unique, $\overline{\eta}$ would work too). Then $g$ is holomorphic on the disk $\{ z : \lvert z\rvert < \lvert\eta\rvert\}$, so the radius of convergence of the MacLaurin series of $g$ is $\lvert\eta\rvert > \lvert\zeta\rvert$.